# Why does Postgres not recognize my DST?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

In my *postgresql.conf* file, my default timezone is set to 'Europe/London'.

Since the DST will be switched off on 30th October, this means that *now* (4th October while I am writing) 'Europe/London' [should correspond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) with '+01'.

I have a `dummy` table with a `time` column of `timestamp with timezone` type.

[Postgres specs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html) state that:

> For  `timestamp with timezone`, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. **If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.**

As for the bold sentence, if I make this insert:

```
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2016-12-25 12:00:00.000')
```

I expect it to be interpreted as a 'Europe/London' timezone, thus `'2016-12-25 12:00:00.000+01'`.

Therefore, when I will retrieve it, I expect to be showed that value (or, at least, the equivalent `'2016-12-25 11:00:00.000+00'`).

Instead, if I do the query

```
SELECT * FROM dummy
```

I am returned this:

```
|time                    |
|timestamp with time zone|
--------------------------
|2016-12-25 12:00:00+00  |
```

I can't get the reason of this behaviour. Is the DST management of 'Europe/London' timezone wrong? Am I missing something?

If I switch to any other timezone, it always works as expected.

Comment: Do you mean when I tried to use different timezones? I just changed the tz at session level by using `SET TIME ZONE` command.

Comment: @DanieleRepici your expectation is not complete, Postgres will assume `timestamptz '2016-12-25 12:00:00.000 Europe/London'`, which is indeed `2016-12-25 12:00:00+00` (i.e. Postgres will use the **time zone**, not its current **offset**).

Comment: @pozs so basically you are saying that it does not take into account the current time to infer the correct offset in this case. Is this behaviour specified somewhere? As for the bold sentence in the quoted documentation, in order to make the conversion, Postgres should be asking itself: "ok, what is the offset for the timezone 'Europe/London'?" and it depends on the current time indeed.

Comment: @DanieleRepici yes. whenever the Postgres docs refer *timezone* it means a time zone, which may or may not contain DST rules. If it does, it will always taken into account. You can set explicit offsets too as time zones: then it will never use DST rules. The [Time Zones section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) of the docs could further clarify on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp you enter *is* interpreted in the `Europe/London` time zone.

On the 25th of December, London will be offset 0 hours from UTC, so noon will be at 12:00 UTC.

Time zone `Europe/London` is *not* the same as time zone `+01`, at least not all the time.

Comment: I've just been stuck into this since yesterday, thank you. It was so trivial :(